# Is setTimeout(task, 0) causing problems in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Chapter 6 "Responsive Interfaces" of "High Performance JavaScript" book by Nicholas C. Zakas says the following thing about Timer Precision:

> Timer resolution on Windows systems is 15 milliseconds, meaning that
>   it will interpret a timer delay of 15 as either 0 or 15, depending on
>   when the system time was last updated. Setting timer delays of less
>   than 15 can cause **browser locking** in Internet Explorer, so the
>   smallest recommended delay is 25 milliseconds (which will end up as
>   either 15 or 30) to ensure a delay of at least 15 milliseconds.

What is the meaning of "browser locking" here? Does that mean that widely used approach `setTimeout(task, 0)` to move a task to the end of UI thread queue can make IE hang?

Comment: never had problems with setTimeout(t, 0), using it since ie6.
duplicated question [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

Comment: 25 ms? That's not even 40 FPS in an animation! ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setTimeout runs your task once, I don't think this will cause a lockup.

My interpretation of your book snippet is that he is referring to *repeated* executions, such as with setInterval. If you set code to execute every 0 milliseconds, then yeah, I could see IE having a problem with that.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. That is what I was thinking too.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using it and no I have not experienced any issues with it. It allows the browser to use time slots for its rendering thread which actually is very useful in some cases.